# Modal View prevents other views from rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this method in my MainViewController:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSLog(@"MAIN CONTAINER WILL ANIMATE");
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

And when I rotate, the NSLog shows up, and everything is perfect. However, if I present a modalViewController from my MainViewController, and then I rotate, the NSLog no longer appears, and my MainViewController never knows that the device got rotated, so when the modalView is dismissed, the interface is not adjusted for the rotation.

Any ideas as to why a modal view can prevent the parent from receiving rotation updates? Is this typical, or must there be something wrong with my setup?

And just to make sure, I tried presenting the modalViewController as a subview via `[mainViewController.view addSubview:modalView.view]`, and the rotation updates took effect properly. It's only when I do `[mainViewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController];` that the updates don't take effect.

Comment: I don't know exactly why Modal View Controller's prevent this method call and I myself have had frustrations with this issue! So I'm afraid I don't know much as to why is doesn't, but I do know how to get around it.
I presume somewhere in your code, you use the line [self.view presentModalViewController:viewController]?
Instead of doing that, simply do [self.view addSubview:viewController.view] (I think its this, don't have the code in front of me)
Basically rather than presenting it modally just add it's view to the current view and all the will/did/is rotating methods should now get called!

Comment: Instead of what..check out my update..maybe that's what you're getting it. But I don't want it to be a subview..I want to get this to work as a modal view..

Comment: Sorry...trigger happy enter key!! :D Editted now!

Comment: The problem is that this is only going to get called when your main view is visible.  Once you add the modal view your main view is no longer going to catch that call for rotation.  If you want you can do something like my response in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131869/autorotation-in-ios5-most-common-reasons-why-it-fails/10132190#10132190  If you use that method, the main view controller will still receive the notifications that a rotation has occured even when it is not visible.  Not sure if that will help you 100% of the way, but it's a start I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely when a view controller is being presented modally, no other view controllers receive any messages at all. That is what modal means in this context.

The obvious solution would be to check the orientation in the viewWillAppear method of your modeless view controller.

Comment: Then in the viewWillAppear, I'd have to custom set the size of everything, since the view still thinks its width is 320, and autoResizing will not have taken place. How do I automatically resize everything to the new view width without manually setting frame sizes?

Comment: You could try setting the autoresizesSubviews property of your main view. That might help.

Comment: In iOS 6 or above, do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews. In viewWillAppear, the dimension of the view would not haven been updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the implementation of:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation. 
    return YES;
 }
```

In both views.

Comment: And what are you returning for the modal view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your layout to the current interface orientation in viewWillAppear. Obviously, because the view is not visible, the animation functions will not be called while the modal view controller is up.